# Avoid jumping of an SVG Text with text-anchor while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

Here is an SVG Text with an anchor:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
  <text x="50" y="30" fill="red" text-anchor="start">I love SVG</text>
</svg>
```

Now if I write a drag function:

```
var dragMove = function (d,i) {
    //d3.select(this).attr("text-anchor", "null"); Does not work
    d3.select(this).attr("x", d3.event.x)
                .attr("y", d3.event.y);
};

var dragEnd = function (d,i) {
    //d3.select(this).attr("text-anchor", "start"); Does not work
};

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                .on("drag", dragMove)
                .on("dragend", dragEnd);

d3.select("svg")
    .select("text")
    .call(drag);
```

It jumps after you drag it depending to its anchor position. Is there a solution to this?

I tried setting the anchor-text to null and then re-set it again but that does not work. I do not want the user experience of dragging to change at all. Not even when the dragging finishes.

Any idea?

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sewVr/

Comment: I don't think it's possible with d3 but you could use jQuery. Check out the offsetX and offsetY properties

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/ You could try to use native drag and drop api's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by saving how much were the `x` and `y` offset between the place where the mouse click happened and the origin of the `text` element. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/twKD9/

Comment: Your method works well when there is a viewBox attribute involved as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use `d3.event.dx` and `d3.event.dy` to get the relative drag position change and apply it in your `dragMove()` function.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sewVr/1/

Comment: This is more general approach than my answer.

Comment: This does not work when there is a viewbox attribute enabled. Is there a way of working it out?!

Comment: That makes it a bit trickier.  It should be possible, but you would need to scale dx and dy using the matrix you get back from getCTM() (an SVG DOM function).  See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable .  d3 might also have built-in function to help with that, but I am not familiar enough with d3 to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Otherwise, if you can, make sure width and height are the same as the width and height of your viewBox.  So that the scaling is 1:1.

Comment: BigBadaboom, please check musically_ut's approach below, because it actually works out of the box for SVG with viewBox attribute enabled.